# Does the ending change if you collect all 200 strawberries?

Tags: celeste

I think very recently, the last of the 200 strawberries has been found. You can get the last strawberry by completing chapter 1 without using the dash once. (Yes, it's possible, I actually got it myself... my death count is at over 800...)

In the ending, Madeline makes a strawberry pie, which has a different quality depending on how many strawberries the player has collected.

Has anyone collected all 200 strawberries yet? Does the ending change in any way?

Comment: Considering that the golden strawberries are so difficult to obtain they don't even grant an achievement, and the characters' reactions when eating the 175-strawberry pie, there is probably no better ending available. That said, if you want to see for yourself, use assist mode on a different file (because it "marks" the file permanently) and it should be no problem to get them all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need 150 strawberries to achieve the best ending. Collecting all 200 strawberries will add a golden strawberry stamp to your save file, but it will not change the ending.

[The video above by *Git Gud*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mcw64ljKK3w) shows that there are 5 different endings for Celeste. I have transcribed each ending below with the number of strawberries needed and a screenshot of the final pie.

### Ending 1 (0-29 strawberries)

[image: Ending 1 pie]

> **Theo**: I guess this is technically a pie...
>
> **Mr. Oshiro**: Is this some kind of joke, Ms. Madeline?
>
> **Old Woman**: Strawberry pies are supposed to have strawberries in them, dear.

### Ending 2 (30-49 strawberries)

[image: Ending 2 pie]

> **Theo**: Madeline, I super appreciate you baking for us... But I don't think I can eat this.
>
> **Old Woman**: It's the thought that counts.
>
> **Badeline**: You people just can't appreciate good food. I'll eat all of it myself.
>
> **Madeline**: You don't have to do that.
>
> **Badeline**: Yeah... it was an empty threat.

### Ending 3 (50-89 strawberries)

[image: Ending 3 pie]

> **Mr. Oshiro**: The important thing is that you tried your best, Ms. Madeline.
>
> **Badeline**: Who invited this guy?
>
> **Theo**: Come on, it's really good.
>
> **Old Woman**: I've certainly had worse.
>
> **Theo**: Thanks for the pie, Madeline.

### Ending 4 (90-149 strawberries)

[image: Ending 4 pie]

> **Old Woman**: I'm impressed! This gives my baking a run for its money.
>
> **Badeline**: Not bad.
>
> **Theo**: Holy crap! This is so tasty!
>
> **Mr. Oshiro**: Ms. Madeline, are you available to cater our re-opening banquet?
>
> **Theo**: Can I take a slice home for Alex? She'll die when she tastes this.

### Ending 5 (150-200 strawberries)

[image: Ending 5 pie]

> **Theo**: Madeline. This is the best thing I've ever tasted!
>
> **Madeline**: Come on. Be honest.
>
> **Old Woman**: He's right, dear. This is delicious.
>
> **Mr. Oshiro**: It's truly magnificent, Ms. Madeline. A symphony for the taste buds!
>
> **Badeline**: Can I take partial credit for this?
>
> **Madeline**: Wow, thanks everyone. I worked really hard for it.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

According to the uploader of this [100% deathless run on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvfHBM2ROwg), collecting 200 strawberries adds a golden strawberry stamp to your file, but the ending scene is the same as it is with 175 strawberries.

Comment: To  be clear, the response in question is in the video comments, not the video itself.

Comment: * The same as with 150 strawberries.